# Getting a color from clicking the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I am currently making an earth in unity 3d, and I wanted to interact the earth by clicking it with mouse. To do this, I tried to use color.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0uaQ.png)

For example, thinking that the blue thingy is my mouse pointer, if I click there, red will be returned.

However, since there was a distance between the camera and the earth, the system did not know where I was clicking on.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raycast from the mouse position and check if it hits any object and get it's color

```cs
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

if(hit.collider && hit.collider.TryGetComponent<Renderer>(out Renderer renderer)) {
    Color color = renderer.material.color;
}
```

Comment: Btw, there is one problem. I get the message "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is there any reasons why this happens? One thing I know is that I did not use renderer that is in unity.

Comment: I think this happened because there’s a case when the ray doesnt even hit anything, i modified my answer